# Recursive Definition of Is Equal To

Tags: proof-writing, induction, recurrence-relations

I'm working through some of the intro problems in Sudkamp's Languages and Machines (basically an intro book to finite automata, context free grammars, Turing machines, etc), and I'm struggling a bit with recursive definitions and the mathematical preliminaries. Can anyone explain how to get going with the following problem?

Give a recursive definition of the relation "is equal to" on N x N using the operator s.

N x N a relation of the Natural numbers, and the operator s refers to the "successor operator." I assume this has to do with the definition of addition. The sequence is 0, s(0), s(s(0)),... which equals 0, 1, 2, ...

I suspect that this can be solved with mathematical induction, but I'm not sure what the base case should even be.

Comment: I dont think so many people know Sudkamp. Please give more mathematical info.

Comment: `on N x N using the operator s` is ambiguous. please give an example. and make clear what space you are working on.

Comment: To make what @Arashium says a bit clearer, a _relation_ on $\Bbb N$ is usually interpreted as a subset of $\Bbb N\times \Bbb N$, while a (binary) _operation_ on $\Bbb N$ is in reality a function from $\Bbb N \times\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$. You need to have this in mind when you write. The operation $s$ is _unary_, and thus a function from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

Ref to :

- Thomas Sudkamp, [Languages and machines : An Introduction to the Theory of Computer Science](https://books.google.it/books?id=UMcKJwAACAAJ) (2nd ed - 1997), **Exercise 24**, page 34.

We have to define a *relation* :

> $Eq \subseteq \mathbb N \times \mathbb N$

defined thorugh the following equations :

> $Eq(0,0)=$**true**
>
> $Eq(0,s(n))=$**false**
>
> $Eq(s(m),0)=$**false**
>
> $Eq(s(m),s(n))=Eq(m,n)$.

---

Thus, "mimicking" the **Example 1.5.2**, page 23, we must have :

> *i)* Basis : $[0,0] \in EQ$.
>
> *ii)* Recursive step : if $[n,m] \in EQ$, then $[s(n),s(m)] \in EQ$.
>
> *iii)* Closure : $[n,m] \in EQ$ only if it can be obtained from $[0,0]$ by a finite number of applications of the operations in the recursive step.